Generating function of $P_{11}^{2n}$
I am studying Markov chains and I am interested in calculating the generating function ($U(s)$) of $P_{11}^{2n}$, where
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix}
          0 & 1-\alpha & \alpha & 0 \\
           1-\alpha & 0 & 0 & \alpha \\
           \alpha & 0 & 0 & 1 - \alpha \\
           0 & \alpha & 1 - \alpha & 0
\end{pmatrix}
, \quad 0 < \alpha < 1$$
with $I = \{ 1,2,3,4 \}$. I found $P_{11}^{2n} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k} \alpha^{2k} (1-\alpha)^{2n-2k} = \frac{1}{2}(1+(2\alpha -1)^{2n})$. Now for definition of $U(s)$ we have
$$
U(s) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} P_{11}^n s^n = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} P_{11}^{2n} s^{2n}
$$
Is this correct? I have a confusion with the index of the sum, it is not supposed to start from $0$ since cannot return to state $1$ in $0$ steps, so the sum must start from 1 to have $n$ even.

Your first summation is incorrect. It should be
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \left(\begin{array}{c} 2n\\2k\end{array} \right) \alpha^{2k} (1-\alpha)^{2n-2k} = [\alpha^{2}+ (1-\alpha)^{2}]^{n}.
$$
It is correct to have $P_{11}^{(0)}=1$. If the chain is at state $1$, it will definitely (i.e. with probability 1) still be at $1$ after $0$ time steps.
